Does the GraphQL protocol support protected again simultaneous updates?
I'm using multiple graphql clients to do updates against graphql services. During my test I notice that the updates concurrent clients keep updating each others updates. Are there mechanisms similar to HTTP ETag/If-Match (or other techniques) to make update requests conditional? Or, does this all depend on the service implementing graphql?
